# How to change an UILabel's text when an UIStepper tapped programmatically in Swift 4, if they are both in an UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, uistepper

Swift 4: I have a static cell (grouped style). I just add an UILabel and an UIStepper to the cell. Now I would like to change the UILabel's text, when I tap the UIStepper. Just like the picture:

[image: Picture 1]

Here are my codes:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(first[indexPath.row])"


    let step = UIStepper()
    let label = UILabel()

    func labelValueChanged(sender:UIStepper!) {
        label.text = "\(Int(step.value))"
    }

    cell.addSubview(step)
    step.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    step.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    step.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 94).isActive = true
    step.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 29).isActive = true
    step.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    step.addTarget(self, action: #selector(labelValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)



    cell.addSubview(label)
    label.text = "0"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 21).isActive = true
    label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor, constant: -124).isActive = true

}
```

There will be an error if the labelValueChanged function was added inside of the cell: `Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'labelValueChanged(sender:)'`

[image: Picture]

But if the labelValueChanged function was added outside of the cell, the label and UIStepper's value will be unavailable.

Is there any way to make it happen? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might create a custom cell subclass and let it manage its own stepper and label.

Comment: @rmaddy My question is If I removed the function out of the cell, how can I get the label’s text changed.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks, Phillip. I’ll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make it happen?

One way to do it is to use the stepper's `tag` property to store the cell's row number. The view controller can then get the stepper's `tag` and know what row is affected. That's not ideal, though, because it doesn't really work well for tables with multiple sections.

> There will be an error if the labelValueChanged function was added inside of the cell: `Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'labelValueChanged(sender:)'`

I can't quite tell why you're having this problem, but you can certainly add an IBAction method to a custom table cell class, set the stepper's target to the cell, and set the stepper's action to that method. And you don't need to set the target and action programmatically -- you can configure them in the storyboard editor. A good strategy would be to have the cell then delegate the real work to some controller object, probably the view controller. Setting the stepper's target to the cell lets the cell call a method in the controller that includes more parameters than just a simple action (which only has a `sender` parameter), so you can pass along the row and section, how the stepper value changed, and anything else you might need.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. As you said, an IBAction will be much easier way. Yes, I tried it before asking for help. But as you may see, Xcode will get stuck sometimes if I had 10 sections or more. That’s why I turned to pure codes. UIStepper, DatePicker, and static sections are nightmare.